# How can I clear all but the top two activities in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-task, onnewintent

My App's activity structure can be any of the following.

> Case1: A > B > B > B > D
>
> Case2: A > B > D
>
> Case3: A > B > B > B > C > D

There is an option in Activity D that when selected I would like to end up with this on the stack:

> A > B

Where ideally, B is a new instance of that activity. At first I thought I had found my solution in `ACTIVITY_FLAG_CLEAR_TOP`, which works in case 2. However, in either case 1 or case 3 it ends up leaving all the 'underbelly' B activities intact as so. A > B > B > B.

Scouring the internet I have found a potential workaround solution in using `ACTIVITY_FLAG_CLEAR_TOP` and `ACTIVITY_FLAG_SINGLE_TOP` and using that to start activity A and capturing an extra in the onNewIntent or onCreate methods to immediately start an instance of activity B.

However, That seems rather awkward to me, code-wise. Especially considering activity A is a homescreen that should (from an intuitive flow of things) only be accessed when switching between accounts (technically speaking, characters, as it is a game).

Another workaround that I've thought of is to insert a loading screen activity between A and B that I can "recall" back to and restart B from. However, that also seems slightly obtuse because it is a simple app and there really isn't anything that needs loading time. Also, there is the possibility of putting all the activities from Activity B onwards in a new task but that seems even more obtuse and unnecessary.

TLDR: Are there any other methods to clear off all the stack except A and a new activity B? Or is the answer that I am doomed to use a workaround.

EDIT: I do need the `back stack` up to and until the user selects the specific option in Activity D. For example, if they just hit the back key in Activity D or in one of the B (or C) activities, I do need it to go back to the immediately preceding activity (as it does by default), so finishing the activities as I go along will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't need `Activity` to be added on `back stack` then while calling `New Activities with Intent` just call `finish()` method.

for example,
If your calling sequence is

> A -> B -> C -> D -> E

and while coming back from E it should get back to B. then,

while launching `Activity D` from `Activity C` then call `finish()` along with it and while launching `Activity E` from `Activity D` call `finish()` along with it.

Comment: I should specify that I do need the `back stack` intact up to and until the specific option is selected in Activity D. I'll edit my question to include this.